# How to extend an MVC Controller built in a dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I'm using the SumoSoft.CMS.Mvc, which is a Nuget package that installs in your MVC project some Views and dlls in order to quickly build a CMS.

These dlls include the code of some controllers like "SumoSoft.CMS.BlogController". Is there any way to extend these Controllers in order to add a new Action?

For example, the SumoSoft.CMS currently provides the actions:

/Blog/Index

/Blog/Article

What if I want to create the action:

/Blog/Category

Comment: as long as its not sealed, you could inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it would simply work like

```
public class YourController : SumoSoft.CMS.BlogController
{
    public ActionResult YourAction
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that too, but this will create a link like /YourController/YourAction, while what I'm trying to achieve is /Blog/YourAction

Comment: Why don't you try to use the `[Route()]` attribute and specify the route if that's the case?

Comment: Thanks Martin, that sounds promising, but I can't make it work... I've added routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); but now I'm not sure about the code to write in the Controller

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your routing table to add an explicit route for your custom action.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "CustomBlogRouteActionJackson",
        url: "Blog/CustomAction",
        defaults: new { controller = "YourControllerNameWhichInheritsFromThatLibrariesController", action = "YourAwesomeActionName" }
    );
```

Make sure this goes above any other routes.

Comment: Yeah, this actually makes sense, although I'm interested in Martin's suggestion about using Route attributes. What would it be the right syntax for that in the Controller?